# ¿Como enviar y capturar valor de input readonly en symfony 3.0?

Tags: html, symfony3, entrada

Buenas a todos.
Espero me puedan ayudar con la presente consulta:
Estoy desarrollando algo en symfony 3.0 y tengo una vista donde tengo varios `input` y algunos de ellos los coloqué `ReadOnly` para que no puedan ser cambiados por el usuario y porque he leído que así se envía el valor, ya que con `Disabled` no se puede enviar.
Pero, a pesar de que son `ReadOnly`, no envía el valor, es más si utilizo `$_POST` para ver si en el arreglo de variables aparece el control, me arroja el mensaje de `Undefined Index` y en definitiva no puedo capturar ese valor en el controlador de symfony.
Agrego parte del código de la vista y del controlador a ver si me pueden ayudar. Gracias.

**Código Vista en Syfony:**

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 50%">Valor Total Factura:</th>
    <th style="width: 50%">$<input style="width: 95%; border: none; text-align:right" readonly name="val_factura" id="val_factura" value="{{ facturas.valorCobro|number_format(2,'.',',') }}" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 50%">Valor Total a Asignar:</th>
    <th style="width: 50%">$<input style="width: 95%; border: none; text-align:right" readonly name="val_asignado" id="val_asignado" value="{{ facturas.valorCobro|number_format(2,'.',',') }}" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 50%">Saldo por Asignar:</th>
    <th style="width: 50%">$<input style="width: 95%; border: none; text-align:right" readonly name="sal_factura" id="sal_factura" value="{{ 0|number_format(2,'.',',') }}" /></th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Código Controlador Symfony:**

```
if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") { 
  //Si el metodo es post para procesar el envio del formulario con capitulo asignado en el select
  $nomCapitulo=$request->request->get('nom_capitulo');
  $valAsignar=$request->request->get('val_asignar');
  $valCapitulo=$request->request->get('val_inicial');
  $valSaldo=$request->request->get('val_saldo');
  $valFactura=$request->request->get('val_factura');
  $valAsignado=$request->request->get('val_asignado');
  $salFactura=$request->request->get('sal_factura');
  $idFactura=$request->request->get('idFactura');
  $numFactura=$request->request->get('numFactura');
```

Hacer las consultas de las bases de datos para evitar exceso de código o redundancia de consultas

```
$idfact = $idFactura;
$numfact = $numFactura;
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Comment: puedes hacer un `dump` de `$request->request->all()` y compartir con nosotros qué te está llegando?

Comment: Considerando la respuesta, votando por cerrar como "error tipográfico"

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que tenía una vista anterior donde enviaba un sólo registro y modifiqué de ahí casi todo para agregar controles o los input dinámicamente para enviar varios registros si el usuario lo desea y resulta que inconscientemente o lapsus no sé, los dejé por fuera del formulario.

Imagínense, cuándo los iba a enviar! De todos modos, comento la respuesta por si le pasa a alguién más, aúnque no lo creo. Caso cerrado.